# What is this three dimensional curve that looks like an infinity sign called?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, terminology, physics, applied-mathematics

What is this three dimensional curve that looks like an infinity sign called? (Is there a known parametric equation for it?)

[image: Rydberg_dihedral_kernel_KPCA_visualization_dim_3]

It was generated with [this Sagemath - script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJztVt-P2jgQfkfif3DZh9qQhE3CVu3qeKgOaR9OJ52EVKEidmUSA4bESW3Dbv_7G_8IEJbtPfThpKo8mPHMN589M_bEK1mVSO0KRqWIcpZVZV0prnklEAdRavQXk4IV__z5udvxGrEv6--IKiTqbqfbydkK7XaYBkty3-0g-Emm91KgeFjSF6vv9xNnufGmdZZbw2MyxLS_JA3PWtLyb6rxbnfBVdBymVM0u0cl1ZK_4Pncr4lWlUQUcYFmCysvnXzkzPMre1PfpFkFLJQM4H8JiDDpe86TL9-wXNLis1gXTIFDMGuIbtBG61rdDyFKvYmUptmOvWQbKtYsgjwOv-2ZMolUw_Tuw93HT7fDnGkmSy6o0GG1CtX3smQQTBa6mMJnrjfhXnAd5pyuK0ELt9QDGp9nBs-I30ItudD4wU8nAHuIuDgwqRhuYyYNxoAmkayeFT6qIlrXTOQ4VPsSTyaEQHDPPNtovm6TNCw-icdSgGXOF1Fe6adaVvk-M9j5dkGG3iIqWWLSt0o_ISQSmCC-QvzdeItYoRiKbQG5KaA0ecQFExDtICautNtrllfF-kLlhEGm_odKHQ6Q3pxD_HOMebAlwYFK3MueegOlJQZGqyVuBrfDzgi5jDsOdoOEXMbstAvyw6Kwl5pCLY-1ORzmdpXFf6Tak7-1JjQHjd3FaGfb9YfW1fjVzyv6yQMb2Q6KryTzC8t0JX_3mXbdDi4rP1O2t8r0ZpVsof_YLnyRbvw9jpMAhhSGxAzxyEhmSEc9gN4YFUR-C-It_CMzf0z6Bv6YoBAZMU7NMLJKM4zQwOBShxudcEkLl45aeufq9NY_sf6p8R9c4tKWatSs2t5N2qiSc-7QczshbYSRF5JGkzQav4PYZePXi6rbMWdGnLXIuySI79Lmws6g7k3vFP4gfwXdfLZwE3fIe2LcO9oN49QwfvUkZ7gpQoCckpPBX5Oe6xZA3QuudJApueZCJXSHe3R74eU-meb0g9sVP3CyHq8fRNPTp6Fx0hC-gpBKZjZ3fEBi8WTfl4IJrcZpgHbWMn5fS_vw3GuWvz-jmT2diHIgOqONVlyfrPj1t6gVvIuhRRepDa3ZOaaGFeoKgKqNPMMUBWAKLtibCFzXg6IgwF49Y_Iv4X060Q==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), where you can zoom in 3d in your browser.
The background lies in the following formula of a positive semidefinite matrix, which then is processed with Kernel-PCA to be visualized in 3dim and is [related to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396276/simplex-invariants?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455470/a-rkhs-interpretation-of-the-rydberg-formula-for-hydrogen-and-an-application-for).

In the book "Matrices and Graphs in Geometry" by Miroslav Fiedler, we have the following generalisation of the sum of angles equals $\pi$ in triangles:

[image: theorem_dihedral_kernel]

In this case, which we are looking at, we have:

$$G_n^{-1} = (d_1^T,d_2^T,\dots,d_n^T)$$

where

$$G_n = (1/\max(i,j)^2)_{1 \le i,j \le n}$$

is a Gram matrix and $d_{n+1} := \sum_{i=1}^n d_i$. Aftwerwards we treat the entries in the positive semidefinite matrix above as a p.s.d. kernel and thus can visualize its entries $1,\cdots,n+1$ with KernelPCA to get the picture above.

Visualized (with KernelPCA) in 2dim, it looks like this:

[image: Rydberg_dihedral_kernel_KPCA_visualization_dim_2]

**Edit**:
Changing the kernel to $K(a,b) = \frac{k(a,b)}{\sqrt{k(a,a)k(b,b}} = \frac{\min(a,b)}{\max(a,b)}$ will give us [the following surface in 3d](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJztV1GP2jgQfkfiP_jYh9qQBEjY6ro6HqpDtw-nk6oiVaiIRSYxwZA4qW2yu_31HccJJLB71akPJ1Xlwdjjb2Y8840nyVZmKVKHhFEpvIiFWZpnimueCcRhKjX6m0nBkg9_vu92Kok4pvkzogqJvNvpdiK2RZJGWJC7bgfBTzJ9lALlMouOoca55ClbR7zgKpMKYKTWOhwwdTa12k2lR_ubYUqfyq1-329v-n1MBxsyxHEYWYRxfVo9BEOMwQCxMGIMGH-NY6VclNCTj_o0saTpP1Tjw-EikISmm4iixR1KqZb8CS-X1cnRNpOIIi7QYlXON3buSC7i6cfZXyfjSRbfX9nflskPef7sJVzQJK5zDujUQl45iAHg_34ar6QOnxmIoiYDlRv1RZpTwg4lA_jfAML1-5WXsy7fsUjS5L2IE6ZAwVmcqEQ7rXN1N4Qk652nNA0P7CncUREzD2ps-OXIlCkyNQxu397-_m40jJhmErihQrvZ1lXPacogvNC1UbqPXO_co-DajTiNM8iWdXWPpk3m8KJi-wbKTmh8Xy1nALv3uCiYVAy3MbMaY0AzT2aPCp9EHs1zJiLsqmOKZzNCILhHHu40j9tGZhdlVpMDO0u-8qJMr-sbAZL9CmrY7ohMppj0S2G1IMAUJohvEf9tukcsUQyNS0q5oVSaPOKECYh2MCaW7P1LO1dkfaJyxiBT_wNTRQHpjTjEv8SYO3viFFTiXrjuDZSW2NxLIyV2BZezXBFyGffYOQx8chmzla7Iv5LCnnIKXJ64KYpl6WX1nVRXxl_zCY1TV5eqnW3bO1tX42evV_SDBVu3qOtkfmKhzuSvPtPmrbBZ-RHaXqPpVZZKov_YryqSbqp7PPYdGAIYfDOMJ2ZmhmDSA-iNEUHkI5iO4B-Z9YPfN_AHH7nITMeBGSal0AwTNDC4wOImZ5zfwgWTltyqWnmp75f6gdEfXOKClmhSe22fJqhFftO2W9m2k6CeTKqJX0v8WlKdYGyz8fNF1e2YmhHnmgkm75zgdlRf2AXwXvdOAZVkpZ9Bulys7MKWeU9Me46o9o3NubH5uTLTwM0RAuScXG2c37jAes-pG1z7RQzP4Q4wHjNR0AR6BSYNQ9WN60E_kXmWPH_PTo170YjtXtbEdUebv6hCJXSrOzS60LKPcHMbQe0FPVAqNa5f0ObnR1WtpIEOBQlOmTnc6WUfi3X5LSCY0GoaOOhQ7kzf5LL8SDhqFr1pmFmsz4YiMNQw6225Pu_i62djK3gbQ8ucp3Y0Zw1MA52DrzwDFdXWcRT_yqYj77ahliQAhhdt1oY2EDhJBnlOwGH2iMk3ocq-jw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

[image: visualization_rydberg_angle_kernel_kpca_3dim_pic_1]

[image: visualization_rydberg_angle_kernel_kpca_3dim_pic_2]

[image: visualization_rydberg_angle_kernel_kpca_3dim_pic_3]

I would also be intersted to know what this surface is called, if it has a name.

Comment: number-theory? physics? applied-mathematics? but not "terminology"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Ha, ha, very funny. "number-theory" because of the p.d. kernel $1/\max(a,b)^2$ on natural numbers. "applied-mathematics" because of the applied KernelPCA method and "physics" because of the question linked to the Rydberg formula. I know it is an unusual combination, but I did not know how to better tag it.

Comment: Fair enough. But since your question asks how something is called, I'd encourage you to add the "terminology" tag. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, every curve that has the shape of the usual infinity sign is called "lemniscate". Now, we also have a curve belonging to the same family, so we could call it a 3D lemniscate and then we are free to specify something else in order to distinguish it from the rest (e.g., "helical lemniscate", "double 3D lemniscate", and so forth).

Furthermore, the lemniscate has the property to be the inverse curve of the hyperbola with respect to its center (see [Lemniscate (MathWorld)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html)) and this is consistent with the 2D projection shown in Figure 2.

Comment: thanks , i knew the word lemniscate but i was searching for a 3d version so to say.

Comment: Yes, I know...  my point is that as "the lemniscate resembles some toric sections when the cutting plane is tangent to the torus along the circumference of its central hole", you can simply extend the original definition by generalizing the environmental space from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$, getting a 3D lemniscate... then you simply have to coin a proper name into the definition, with the equation, you provide.

Comment: thanks again for your insight